# What is the point of defining the lie algebra of the proper Lorentz group in a "covariant" way?

Tags: group-representations, lie-algebra, representation-theory, covariance, lorentz-symmetry

In Muller-Kirsten's book [Introduction to Supersymmetry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814293423), the author first defines the  proper Lorentz group's lie algebra basis in the standard manner - antisymmetric matrices consisting of $0$s and $\pm 1$s. He then says using this basis we can construct a "covariant formalism". Specifically, he goes on to define the mixed tensor

$$ (M_{\rho \sigma})^{\mu}_{\hspace{2mm}\nu} = i(\eta_{\sigma \nu}\delta_{\rho}^{\hspace{2mm}\mu} - \eta_{\rho \nu}\delta_{\sigma}^{\hspace{2mm}\mu})$$

which encodes the aforementioned standard basis (the $i$ here being part of the physics convention for lie algebras).

So firstly, what is the point of encoding the lie algebra in a mixed tensor? Secondly, why is this a "covariant formalism" when it is neither a pure covariant or contravariant tensor?

Answer (score 1):

The relevance of this definition is that all indices are raised/lowered by contraction with the metric, as usual, which is not immediately obvious from the mere matrix definition. An object whose indices are all such proper Lorentz indices is said to "behave covariantly", no matter whether it is a co- or contravariant object or a mixture, and hence this is a "covariant formalism".

Comment: What insight does the existence of such a formalism give us? So tensors have specific transformation properties; does changing coordinates, thereby changing the tensor's coordinate description represent changing the lie algebra basis in accordance with the transformation?